# Is it possible to checkout a beta version of WordPress via github?

Tags: git, github

I know how to check out current versions of WordPress using via `git fetch --tags` but I only see current and past versions, not betas. Is it possible to get access to betas through github?

Comment: Isn't the 3.7 branch the latest and greatest?

Comment: I think checking out master will be the latest.